# Where is List("String") described in API?

Tags: scala

When I create a new List of Strings : `val lines = List("this is a test" , "a new test")` this calls method apply : `override def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] = xs.toList` which in this case returns a List[String]

Reading Scala doc for List : http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List

```
def apply(n: Int): A

Selects an element by its index in the sequence.
```

Why is this different ? Is there a section in API where can view a description of apply for creating a new List ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're messing List **object**'s apply with List **class**' apply.

First one creates list (note big O at the top, it stands for an object):

[image]

Returned *instance of class* List has it's own apply method:

[image]

You can switch between [class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List) and [object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List$) scaladoc by clicking that huge letter.